# Best way to reference an object property

Tags: javascript

Let say I have an object with

```
let product =
   { id:1,
     model:2
   }
```

I can reference the id by

```
const productId = product.id
```

Or I can also do

```
const newProductCreated = Object.assign({}, product)
```

then reference by `newProductCreated.id`

Which would be the best way for me to reference the id?

Comment: It depends what you mean by "*best*". I'd say `var productId = product.id`, as due to your use of `const`, neither of your examples will work in ES5 without transpilation.

Comment: The two results are different ... so the best way is the way that is appropriate for the circumstance (though, the second way makes absolutely no sense)

Comment: Have you tested the second alternative? I'm getting `{}`...

Comment: Right, I think that has something to do with browser incompatibility with  ES5, I have switched to an alternative  in my answer for the second option.

Comment: `Or I can also do`  - how is `productData.createProduct` even relevant? it's like you are cherry picking snippets of code that are not even related and somehow making them relevant to each other

Comment: `I think that has something to do with browser incompatibility` no, it's that you think two things are the same when they are not

Comment: Hello have made relevant editing on it @JaromandaX . Pls check thank you

Comment: `const newProductCreated = Object.assign({}, product.id)` also produces `{}` ... just like `{...product.id}` - there's a difference between objects and primitives that you fail to grasp

Comment: my guess is that the object you are dealing with at your end is not as simple as what you've presented in the question ... and what you've presented  in all iterations of your questions is nonsense, since the two "methods" result in completely different results

Comment: I would do something like this: 

let product = { 
   id:1,
   model:2
}

var productId = p => p.id;

productId(product);

Comment: First of all why complicate things. In my opinion best is what is readable,simple, easily understandable and not tricky. So `var productId = product.id` seems to be the one as stated by @ObsidianAge.

Comment: OK, now the question makes more sense ... the answer is ... depends entirely on what you need ... at least now the code produces something meaningful though

Comment: why would you want to clone the object if you're just referencing a property? I would just destructure it. `const { id } = product;`

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with the Redux/'Flux' methedology, the second method makes sense, it is not how you should be using it.

Assuming you are trying to create a shallow copy of the object, you can simply do this:

```
const productCopy = { ...product };
// or const productCopy = Object.assign({}, product) if you can't support ES6
```

From there, you can make respective changes to the properties within `productCopy` without affecting the original `product`.

```
productCopy.model = 3;
// console.log(productCopy) prints out the modified object
// console.log(product) prints out the original object
```

This will be conform to the immutable update patterns.